# Google Apps Script does not fully execute for other users after V8 was introduced

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, v8

I wrote a script (with a lot of assistance from the good folks here) that copies a folder (and contents) on Google Drive using Google Sheets Scripts.

It worked fine for a long time but then I enabled the V8 engine (disabled now). The problem is, it still works for me (and maybe two other users) but does not work for everyone else. I'm not a programmer but I learned enough to help me automate some tasks on Excel/ Sheets.

So far, I've tried rechecking all the permissions, creating a brand new sheet, assigning new owners, removing triggers, learning more about V8. But it's not really working because I can't even figure out the problem.

I would appreciate any leads.  TIA

PS: We're using shared drives and the Source/Target folder are accessible to all users.

Here's the script:

```
function onClick() {
  ss.getRange("B2:B8").clearContent();
}



function start() {


  var sourceFolder = ss.getRange("B19").getValue() ; // Change every month
  var targetFolder = ss.getRange("B22").getValue();

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder); // Grab the folder we're going to copy
  var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(ss.getRange("B11").getValue()); // Destination for the new folder.
  var target = parentFolder.createFolder(targetFolder); 

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }

}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();
  var prefix = ss.getRange("B23").getValue(); 

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target).setName(prefix + file.getName()); 

  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);

    var NewFolderUrl = target.getUrl()
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B8').setValue(NewFolderUrl);

  }  
  //file.setName(prefix + file.getName());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work for everyone else" - are there any errors? Can you check the logs (`View` -> `Stackdriver Logging`)? Moreover, is the spreadsheet available to all the users as well?

Comment: I've added a button that starts the script on click. When 'most' other users click it, it starts running and says 'Finished Script' but does have the desired output. 

It's supposed to copy over the folder and it's contents and generate a link of the new folder.

However, it does only creates the main folder (no contents) and does not generate a link.

It does not throw any errors.

It's hard to drill down on the problem because the same script works for some users but not all. 

Everyone has the same permissions. The exact same permissions.

Comment: Have you checked the logs in this situation?

Comment: I've checked it from the Apps Script Dashboard and It shows "Completed".

Comment: Even for the users whose executions are not made?

Comment: That's right. but only for the Start Function. No mention of CopyFolders. It even creates the main folder in the right location but it's almost like the 'CopyFolder' function doesn't work for them. It used to be fine before and it ran for everyone. I have not made any changes and neither have the other users.

The ONLY time an error shows up is when I run the 'CopyFolders' function from the script editor on its own and I get TypeError: Cannot call method GetFolders but I think that makes sense because the Start function needs to run before to clear all the undefined stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Have you tried moving the `source` and `target` variables outside of the `start` function and/or declaring them in the `copyFolders` one as well?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. But I did it the other way around, declaring all variables in the Start functions. I'll get someone to do that right now - since it works fine for me - and post another comment.

Comment: Tried declaring variables outside the Start function and also declared in the CopyFolder function. Still the same issue. Script runs but no output like the CopyFolder script didn't run with the Start.

Comment: Can you log the `source` and `target` variables then and see if they're passed correctly by using `console.log(source)` & `console.log(target)`?  Same with `folders` and `files` - can you `log` these as well and check if the values are the expected ones?

Comment: Is this what I should be expecting in the Stackdriver logs? Sorry, I've never used the console before

https://i.imgur.com/e4eSWgY.png

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is `source.getName()` & the same for all the others, in order to check if the function gets the expected & wanted names.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did console.log(source.getName()). Is that what I was supposed to do? 

I got TypeError: Cannot find function getName in object FolderIterator. at start(Code:26)

Comment: Let us continue this conversation in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215517/) @Glorfindel

Comment: New to SO. Can't use the chat feature until I have enough rep points. I ran your edits and  it worked for me. i got the names of all the right files that were supposed to pass through the function. However, when my colleague did it, we got "No logs available".

Comment: That means most likely the ‘start’ and ‘copyFolder’ are never actually ran OR the values for the mentioned variables are not set accordingly hence the script does not run as expected. Can you confirm the sctupy is attached to the spreadsheet AND/OR the values are retrieved from it accordingly?

Comment: We all use the same spreadsheet to run the script. It's located in a shared-drive so there are no owners.

It used to work for everyone - then one day it stopped. Happened after I enabled V8 (disabled it now). Now, it only works for 3/6 coworkers. Everyone has the same privileges.

Comment: Yes - but is the script attached to the sheet? Can you confirm this by: console.log(ss.getId()); and console.log("start function has been executed"); (in the start function) as well as console.log("copyFolder function has been executed"); (in the copyFolder)?

Comment: Thank you - I tried it out myself. No, surprise; it worked. However, I did get an error on the getId part; even though it worked. "TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object Sheet". I added it at the end of the Start function.

Yes, the script is attached to the sheet. Everyone can access it from the script editor. 

I will wait for someone else to run it and give you the results.

Comment: I got someone else to try it - and once again - no logs. I know the script is attached because there's a 'ClearContents' function attached to a button and it works for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are **not getting any logs** for the users the script doesn't work for, the issue is most likely related to your functions not being executed properly and/or at all.

A issue for this is that the script is not being attached to the spreadsheet. You can try and declare the `ss` variable to the `start` function. Another issue for the behavior mentioned can be caused by passing wrong variables to the functions. You can check that by using `console.log()` and checking if the variables are the expected ones or not.

Moreover, since you share this script with multiple users, you might want to take a look into [Edditor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons). This can make sharing easier as the users will only need to install the add-on.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting);
- [Editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons).

Comment: Thank you so much ale13 for all your help. I tried your steps but ran into the same problem. They did get me thinking and I tried changing the source folder. I got my team to add the source folder to their personal drives, change the name etc.

The solution was much simpler...all that a new person has to do to run the script successfully is open the source folder ONCE (wherever it's located). I did some tests with 4 new users and it seems to hold true :)

Answer (score 1):

Through some trial and error - I've found that all someone had to do to run this script successfully was to open the `SourceFolder` once. It may be because it searches for it based on the file name.