# How to run a trigger from a different account?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm writing this Workspace Sheets Add-On and have this simple [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) set to trigger whenever a the spreadsheet is opened:

```
function whenOpen(e) {
  Logger.log('Open trigger ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
if (currentTriggers.length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('whenOpen').forSpreadsheet(ss).onOpen().create();
}
```

When testing it, I can see that it gets triggered successfully on my own account from project executions and I see a message that looks like `Open trigger {"authMode":"FULL","source":{},"triggerUid":"[...]","user":{[...]}}`.

When I run this from a different account on the same spreadsheet, the event seems to get sent but I just see immediate failure instead with no logs with any additional information:

[image: Failed with no logs]

Perhaps this is some authentication issue? I understand the trigger will be run from the context of the user that installs the trigger (based on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)) but I still expect it to run without error. I thought it might be a scoping issue but I'm already requesting `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` to allow for scripts to run in the background.

My questions:

- Is there any way to get more detailed error messages to why this is failing?
- What is causing this trigger to fail to run?

Comment: This seems weird as I tested it on my side and it actually runs. My testing proved that you only need `editor` permission on the other accounts for the trigger to be triggered. Although the output was unexpected. `Open trigger {"authMode":"FULL","source":{},"triggerUid":"6771708","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}` I was expecting for the script to show the email and nickname of the actual user who opened the sheet or at least the owner's.

Comment: hi @nico, can you try the process from scratch again? maybe something was amiss as I was not able to replicate your issue.

Comment: Hi @nico, I have actually replicated the issue where no logs were showing during other account opening the sheet and results to `failed`. Try refreshing the execution tab. Mine actually shows nothing at first and when I refreshed the tab, it now shows. Have you checked if yours was just a case of delayed logs?

Comment: Maybe these references can help: [How can my Google Apps Script be run by others the Sheet is shared with?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57071543/14606045) or this one [Google Apps Script does not fully execute for other users after V8 was introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389148/14606045)

Comment: I will try to make another simple add-on to see if I can replicate it with a bare-bones app. I still have no information inside the failed executions.

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue. I have been running this as a Workspace Add-On instead of an Editor Add-On. Could that explain the difference in behavior I wonder?

Comment: hi @nico, I'm all out of idea as of now. Were the references above helped you in any way? We might as well wait for others to chime in with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't make this clear but there are two types of add-ons:

- Editor Add-Ons which are installed to the document
- Workspace Add-Ons which are installed to the user

See: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/types

I needed to use an Editor Add-On to have the behavior I wanted.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't able to mention I was using Editor Add-On. Glad you were able to resolve your issue.

Comment: @NaziA No worries, this is fairly obscure -- thanks for your help.